# Intermittent IIS/Azure Errors

Tags: iis, azure, web-config

I have a web app running on an Azure VM. It is single-code base, multiple db's. Based on appsettings in the web.config (basically localhost or production), it knows which database to use.

Just recently I made a simple update and pushed the code to the server. I use git to pull files from the repo to the server, then copy my dll's from my local dev machine to the server.  It's not the best, but it's worked for now.

Since this last update, I've been getting intermittent database connection errors (nothing related to the udpates I pushed). Based on the errors I'm receiving, the app is looking for the wrong database (what's set for localhost) instead of using the production databases. It fails on login since the db doesn't exist. I can log in, sometimes customers can't, even at the same time. Then I switch to a new computer and it doesn't work. I've restarted IIS and that's solved it once, but I am totally at a loss about what is going on.

Thoughts:

- Could the dll or build be corrupted?
- Is something wrong with IIS?
- Other Ideas?

Any help, much appreciated!
Scott J.

Edit: It seems only to happen on the login. I changed the login page back to the original. It worked, now it stopped working sometimes again. Very frustrating!

Error Message:

```
Cannot open database "companyA" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Production'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "companyA" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Production'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at PLM.Providers.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SqlConnectionHelper.cs:line 127 at PLM.Providers.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SqlConnectionHelper.cs:line 57 at PLM.Providers.SqlMembershipProvider.GetConnectionHolder() in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SQLMembershipProvider.cs:line 101 at PLM.Providers.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SQLMembershipProvider.cs:line 1704 at PLM.Providers.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SQLMembershipProvider.cs:line 1562 at PLM.Providers.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SQLMembershipProvider.cs:line 1549 at PLM.Providers.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) in C:\Users\Israel\Desktop\ODESK\Scott\PLMMemberhipProvider\SQLMembershipProvider.cs:line 856 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ClientConnectionId:5257f0df-46c9-4faa-bfea-1db4daf509b3
```

Comment: How many instances do you have running? Perhaps you updated one instance incorrectly, or didn't update it at all?

Comment: @BrianReischl I have just one VM, all the sites are running on it. I wish there was a way to debug on the server better. I'm trying to rack my brain to think of what could cause things to appear like intermittent problems, DNS?

Comment: Typically ADO.NET uses connection pooling, so I don't think that a DNS issue would cause this problem. Perhaps the error is coming from some other component (eg, session storage)? What kind of database are you expecting it to connect to? SQL Azure? Also, it would help if you could post errors messages.

Comment: @BrianReischl It's SQL Server Express on the server. I posted the error message.

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows Authentication, rather than passing an application login/password. Is it possible that some of the threads are running with a different principal that can't connect to the DB, or that it gets reset (or not reset) during the login process? Might explain why it works for you and not others.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database are you logging into? I'm hoping that your data is stored in SQL Azure or Azure Storage.

If your production database is created within the worker role, note that your worker role will be periodically re-started by Microsoft whenever your worker's OS needs to be updated, etc. and any locally created files (inc. DB files) will be deleted when the VM reboots.

Comment: @Richard_Turner - No, it's not SQL Azure, but a SQL Server Express instance on the server. VM's are persistent, unlike web roles, etc. Unless I'm missing something.